# jQuery ajaxSuccess multiple calls to create effect seems redundant is there another way?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-ui

The effect I am currently creating is a quick fade-out then a fade-in of the element when the request is successful..

Because the jQuery processes in routine fashion (top to bottom) I can get my effect working with my below "hack"..

But I would like to know if there is a better way to create this effect. Here is what I have now.. I have not been able to find another way to do this:

```
$('#submitButton').ajaxSuccess(function () {
$("#records_results_table").fadeOut();
});

$('#submitButton').ajaxSuccess(function () {
$("#records_results_table").fadeIn();
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try:

```js
$('#submitButton').ajaxSuccess(function () {
    $("#records_results_table").fadeOut(300, function(){
        $(this).fadeIn();
    });
});
```

Comment: Shef, it's the same effect but the code is so much sexier : ) .. I am still in a major learning curve with jQuery.. This actually helps me see how jQquery nesting works as well. Thanks for this!

Comment: Your previous one would not always guarantee a "serialized" action (i.e. first fade out, then fade in). This one is guaranteed to do that. Or you could use @Tomalak's version if you want to stick to the default 300 milliseconds (a.k.a slow) effect duration. If you want to change the effect to take more time, or less time you can use mine.

Comment: @Shef The effect duration doesn't make any difference for my solution.

Comment: Shef, I realized the effect is not very optimized, because the form loader goes before it fades, and I wanted to initial click to initialize the fadeOut.. This is what I am using now but it does not create the fades.. I assume my nesting is screwed up. Do you have any suggestions? $('#submitButton').click(function () {
    $("#records_results_table").fadeOut(300, function(){
        $(this).ajaxSuccess.fadeIn(300, function(){})
    });
});

Comment: @Tomalak: Yes, you are right. I was wrong in my assumption. Here is a  demo to prove your case: http://jsfiddle.net/kKFbn/

Comment: @OldWest: Show me a sample of what you are trying to do, online somewhere. Also, update your question with a short to-the-point description of what you want to happen. So, I can take a look and give a precise answer.

Answer (score 1):

In fact, you can do this:

```
$("#records_results_table").fadeOut().fadeIn();
```

jQuery has the `fx` queue where all animation effects on an element are stored until they can execute. There is no need to use a callback function to append another effect ([see jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Tomalak/85fHZ/)).

Comment: Hmmm.. I see what you are saying, but this code did not create any effect.

Comment: @OldWest: Have you seen the fiddle? If this is not what you want, then maybe I got you wrong?

Comment: No you had it right! I just did not know the bind() on the click needed to be used with your code.

Comment: @OldWest I thought `ajaxSuccess` was your trigger?

Comment: It was, but I realized I wanted .click to be the trigger, so the items would fade out on the click, and then fade in on the success.